# Valor da primeira celula da linha selecionada datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Amigos boa noite.
Estou com dificuldades ao tratar os dados de um datagridview, preciso que quando o usuario clicar na linha, seja atribuido a uma variavel, o valor da celula, da primeira coluna da linha que o usuario selecionou.

Então criei um evento do tipo SelectionChanged, dentro desse evento inclui:

```
 private void clik_table_cliente(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // vamos obter a linha da célula selecionada
        DataGridViewRow linhaAtual = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

        // vamos exibir o índice da linha atual
        int indice = linhaAtual.Index;
        MessageBox.Show("O índice da linha atual é: " + indice);
    }
```

Consigo saber qual a linha selecionada, porem agora, como faço para atribuir o valor da celula, da primeira coluna dessa linha?

Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, você já tem a **linha selecionada**, e já sabe qual **coluna** que quer atualizar, então fica simples.

Acesse a coleção de linhas através da propriedade `Rows`, e a partir da linha desejada acesse a coleção de células (colunas) através de `Cells`. Escolhendo a célula desejada use a propriedade `Value` para configurar o valor. Assim:

```
// configurando valor da primeira coluna, índice 0
dataGridView1.Rows[indice].Cells[0].Value = "meuValorAqui";
```

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado, estava fazendo a sintaxe errado. Valeu

Comment: Que bom que funcionou!